# Problem in luabind with default_converter and tables

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

===Edit===

The problem is actually much simpler than this, any wrapped function that takes a table is causing the problem.  If I wrap a function that takes luabind::object, and call that function with a table argument, then the gc causes an invalid free().  I'm starting to think that this may be some kind of crazy compilation/linking problem, as my compiled luabind dylib has lua symbols in it (resulting in two copies of those symbols, one in that library and one in my binary).  Maybe I have duplicates of some lua static variables or something?  I might just be grasping at straws here.

===Edit===

Using luabind 0.9 and gcc 4.2.1 on mac os x 10.6

I'm seeing what could (maybe?) be a problem with using a default_converter from lua tables.

I'm trying to define converters for various list-like types in my code, specifically std::vector.  When I pass a table to a c++ method with such a default_converter, lua crashes with free() on an invalid pointer as soon as the garbage collector is called.

I'm probably missing something simple here, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

*** Lua Code ***

```
function first ()
 -- Doesn't crash
 -- t = TestClass(1, 3)

 -- Crashes
 t = TestClass({1, 2, 3})

 print(t:get(0))
 print(t:get(1))
 print(t:get(2))
end

function second ()
 print("About to call collectgarbage...")
 collectgarbage()
 print("Done calling collectgarbage!")
end

function test ()
 first()
 second()
end
```

*** C++ Code ***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lua.hpp>

#include <luabind/luabind.hpp>
#include <luabind/operator.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace luabind;

namespace luabind {
 template<typename ListType>
 struct default_converter<std::vector<ListType> > : native_converter_base<std::vector<ListType> > {
   static int compute_score(lua_State* L, int index) {
     return lua_type(L, index) == LUA_TTABLE ? 0 : -1;
   }

   std::vector<ListType> from(lua_State* L, int index) {
     std::vector<ListType> list;
     for (luabind::iterator i(luabind::object(luabind::from_stack(L, index))), end; i != end; ++i)
       list.push_back(luabind::object_cast<ListType>(*i));

     return list;
   }

   void to(lua_State* L, const std::vector<ListType>& l) {
     luabind::object list = luabind::newtable(L);
     for (size_t i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i)
       list[i+1] = l[i];

     list.push(L);
   }
 };
}

class TestClass {
public:
 TestClass(std::vector<int> v) : m_vec(v) {}

 TestClass(int b, int e) {
   for (int i = b; i <= e; ++i)
     m_vec.push_back(i);
 }

 int get(size_t i) const {
   return m_vec[i];
 }

private:
 std::vector<int> m_vec;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 if (argc != 2) {
   cout << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <scriptname>" << endl;
   return -1;
 }

 std::string scriptName = argv[1];
 lua_State* L = (lua_State*) lua_open();
 luaL_openlibs(L);

 open(L);

 module(L)
 [
   class_<TestClass>("TestClass")
     .def(constructor<std::vector<int> >())
     .def(constructor<int, int>())
     .def("get", &TestClass::get)
 ];

 if (luaL_loadfile(L, scriptName.c_str()) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0)) {
   cout << "Script error: " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << endl;
   return -1;
 }

 call_function<void>(globals(L)["test"]);

 lua_close(L);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lua comes with such a nice, simple C API, and yet well-meaning programmers are constantly seduced by false promises from tools like `luabind`.  Much of what it does is interpose complex template metaprogramming hell between you and what is really a very simple interface.  You might consider just using the Lua API directly.

Comment: I know you're trying to help... but that doesn't help.  Other than this problem, I actually have found luabind to be pretty straightforward.  Given the choice between wrapping everything manually, and just using luabind as is *without* default_converter at all, I'd still choose luabind.  Or, I can just manually wrap methods that take table types.  Ultimately, it was my plan to manually develop a lua wrapper, but I'm still in the prototyping stage, and it would have taken me 10x as long to manually roll what I've already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I figured it out.  Turns out that luabind didn't have any problems at all, except for the way it was built.  The jam build system, on mac os x, causes the static lua library to be linked in with the luabind shared library, causing duplicate symbols (and duplicate static variables) when I link my final binary.  It didn't have the *entire* lua library linked in though, so you still have to link liblua.a in again.

Take this explanation with a grain of salt, but it's my best guess; I'm not an expert at how the Mac OS X linker works.  I do know that when I built luabind statically, everything works fine.

So, for anyone building lubabind in mac, build statically.  There are also other problems with the jam built shared lib that you'd have to fix, like the fact that @executable_path is wrong.  Static build was dead simple.